# How to authenticate with the Google Cloud Storage library for app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking at the docs for the [GCS client library for app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/), and I know that I can only allow a certain account to access cloud storage, but how o I make sure only my app engine app can access a certain file/bucket and how do I authenticate my app engine app to GCS?

Comment: did you try the old way? 
`The easiest way to grant app access to a bucket is to use the Google Cloud Console to add the service account name of the app as a team member to the project that contains the bucket.`

Comment: service account looks like `application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: also it seems if you create the app engine project in the new cloud console it automatically makes this connection for you. It then "just works". very nice.