# Google app engine - What is the different between google app engine dev environment and application environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Have a nice day.

I am trying to write a application use google app engine and python to save and retrieve an image to google cloud storage. I researched and I know that, the dev environment is quite different with the application environment such as: when I write code for dev, I no need to declare user for authentication.... So, it means the dev code and the app code are different.

for example about my dev code:

```
BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME',
                             app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
BUCKET = '/' + BUCKET_NAME

logger.debug('BUCKET_NAME: %s' % BUCKET_NAME)

def create_file(filename, filedata, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a file.
    :param filename:
    :param filedata:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    bucket_filename = BUCKET + '/' + filename
    write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    gcs_file = gcs.open(bucket_filename,
                        'w',
                        content_type=kwargs.get('content_type', 'image/jpeg'),
                        options=kwargs.get('options', {}),
                        retry_params=write_retry_params)
    gcs_file.write(filedata)
    gcs_file.close()

    blobstore_filename = '/gs' + bucket_filename
    return blobstore.blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)
```

This function will create and save a file to localhost datastore. For example this is a link of a stored image (blob):

```
http://localhost:8000/datastore/edit/blob_key
```

But, it's just LOCALHOST. And I don't understand the way a file (image) will be created, stored and retrieved to google cloud storage in a application environment.

This isn't clear for me.

Could you please help me to explain more detail about the different between dev environment and app environment? And how to use dev code in app environment?

Answer (score 1):

Local GCS data is stored in your local datastore, using the  `__GSFileInfo__ and __BlobInfo__` entities.

The same code is used for both Dev and Live App environments with no changes required.

Comment: Hi @ChrisC73,  
Thanks a lot for your explain.  
But, Could you please explain me that, Can I use this code to save that file to google cloud storage? Do I have to authenticate with my user? I think I have to  do that but I can not find any docs that guide about that case. In my case, I need save file to gcs, no save to local GCS. Pleas help.

Comment: @SWDream: your GAE app needs to be assigned access rights to the GCS bucket you are using. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607855/how-to-authenticate-with-the-google-cloud-storage-library-for-app-engine) for some more info. Note that the default GCS bucket created for an application will automatically give access to that application. I am unsure if or how you can use the GCS location from a local GAE launcher, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for all. I will research more and will get back you.